# Hiding the server function being called in an ajax request

Tags: ajax

please excuse me for asking this but I have no other option apart from asking you all.

I am using ajax to send some data to a function on the server which does something with the database and then returns some json data.
Now the question is if someone goes through my javascript he/she would come to know of the function on the server to which the data is being posted. for eg: I post some data to a server side function which resides at mysite/postdata.

Cant a person get access to this link and use it. I am sure there should be some way this can be avoided.. just that I dont know....

Comment: Anything you put in JavaScript can and will be seen by users. You'll have to take measures to ensure that malicious users can't retrieve or insert data that they're not supposed to.

Comment: Yeah got that.. thanks.. +1.. had you answered instead of commenting I could have marked you as the best answer though.. :-)

Comment: @jnpcl: Put it as an answer so it can be accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody's posted an answer with more detail.. Here's my comment from above:

> Anything you put in JavaScript can and will be seen by users. You'll have to take measures to ensure that malicious users can't retrieve or insert data that they're not supposed to.